# Unable to satisfy tslint's requirement when adding a new method to global Screen

Tags: typescript, tslint

I want to be able to use screen orientation lock (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock) functionality in different web browsers.

Here is my attempt:

```
export function lock(orientation: OrientationLockType) {
    const lockOrientation: (orientation: OrientationLockType) => boolean = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation || screen.orientation.lock;
    lockOrientation(orientation);
}
```

Visual code flags `screen.mozLockOrientation` because it does not exist in the `Screen` type.

Therefore I add this

```
declare global {
    interface Screen {
        mozLockOrientation: (orientation: OrientationLockType) => boolean;
    }
}
```

However tslint does not like the type declaration of `mozLockOrientation` because it is not a method signature.

So my questions are:

1) What is a method signature and how can I convert the above to a method signature?

2) How can I find out the proper type for `screen.orientation.lock`? I tried `orientation: { lock: (orientation: OrientationLockType) => boolean };` but I wonder if there are more authoritative  sources out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Here is how you would write an equivalent method signature:

```
declare global {
    interface Screen {
        mozLockOrientation(orientation: OrientationLockType): boolean;
    }
}
```

2) If you follow the link from the MDN page to [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#x3-2-screenorientation-interface), it has a WebIDL declaration that is reasonably similar to TypeScript and indicates a return type of `Promise<void>` rather than `boolean`.